# Заокруглить три угла TextView

Tags: android

Как сделать TextView с тремя заокруглеными углами.
Пытался так но неработает

Comment: А как так пытались то?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так кинуть xml в drawable

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFFFFF" /> 
  <corners android:topLeftRadius="2dp" android:topRightRadius="2dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp" android:bottomRightRadius="2dp" /> 
</shape>
```

Ну и у edittext в background прилепить этот drawable

Answer (score 4):

### textview.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:color="#99250000"
    android:width="2dp"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp" android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
    <TextView
    android:background="@drawable/textview"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```